# How can I filter the hits based on their category in algolia instant search

Tags: android, geolocation, algolia

I'd like to filter the hits based on their category, like only shop or coffee.

This is my query:

```
  searcher.setQuery(new Query().setGetRankingInfo(true).setAroundLatLng(new AbstractQuery.LatLng(12.670913552202967, 78.6066235229373)).setAroundRadius(1000));
```

How can I filter the results I'm getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Algolia's Filtering Guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/), where you can learn how filtering works.

With the Android client, you can use the `setFilters` method:

```
Query query = new Query("foo");
query.setFilters("category:coffee");
```

You can find more information in the [client's documentation](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-client-android/com/algolia/search/saas/Query.html#setFilters-java.lang.String-):

```
/**
 * Filter the query with numeric, facet or/and tag filters.
 * <p>
 * The syntax is a SQL like syntax, you can use the OR and AND keywords. The syntax for the underlying numeric, facet and tag filters is the same than in the other filters:
 * {@code available=1 AND (category:Book OR NOT category:Ebook) AND _tags:public date: 1441745506 TO 1441755506 AND inStock > 0 AND author:"John Doe"}
 *
 * @param filters a string following the given syntax.
 * @return the {@link Query} for chaining.
 */
public @NonNull Query setFilters(String filters)
```

Comment: Thanks bro. public @NonNull Query setFilters(String filters) this is for what purpose. And how to use OR and  AND and where to use. please help me

Comment: For example if you want to set a filter for category coffee and brand starbucks, you would do query.setFilters(“category:coffee AND brand:starbucks”)

Comment: Hi @ThofiqAhmed, please accept this answer if it solved your problem ;)